# Exporting SVG element to PDF with jsPDF - Closed

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

## Update - Closed

As for now, what I want to achieve is doable but also it's also very time consuming, to a point were it becomes pointless to me.

Seems that the only way to achieve what I want is to convert the SVG element to canvas (using canvg).

---

I am facing a problem. I have the option to generate a report that informs you about the status of various tasks with an svg check
[image: image is the preview and not the PDF]

(image is the preview and not the PDF). 
You have the option to export this report to PDF using jsPDF.

One key factor that blocks me from solving this is that I don't want to add more plug-ins or extensions to my application.

The whole process of generating the report revolves around a String variable that contains the HTML code and an multi-array that contains arrays with the contents of the future PDF cells. Each inner array resembles a row.

e.g.

```
PdfRows = [["TESTbb", "","John Doe"], ["more subtasks", "", ""], ....];
htmlOutput = "<div class="PrintRow"><div class="PrintCell">TESTbb</div>...</div> ";
```

The svg element gets appended to the string that will be pushed to the PdfRows array and later will get the appropriate prefix and suffix and so on.

```
row += "[" + svg.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').trim() + "] " + subtaskTitle;
```

and finally the PDF will be populated using the `doc.autoTable()` where I provide the columns, rows and other parameters.

The output I get is this,
[image: this is the generated PDF]

 where as you can see, in comparison to the previous image, the SVG element is missing.

I hope I have provided you with enough information. 
Thanks in advance!